# Does it make sense to add checksums to archived data?

Tags: archiving, dvd-burning, blu-ray, checksum

We want to archive some data for long term storage on optical media (M-Disks).

Does it make sense to create checksums for all files beforehand and burn them alongside the data onto the M-Disks?

This way one could verify the data integrity of the media without the need to store the checksums seperately.

Does this even work or will the burned data on a CD/DVD/Blueray differ from what was on the HHDs filesystem?

And if so how could one prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to checksum those on the file system which you know it's not corrupt in an archive format, and then when written to the other media to checksum it there to ensure it's not changed.

The checksum should be based on the content of the data files where it rests so where you store it to should not matter or affect the checksum.

With optical media the data written to it may degrade or become damaged over time. This could change the content of the data or it may become corrupt.

It's important to do checksum validation routinely or before using data from the media, confirming it still matches the checksum value it was in its confirmed valid state before you copied it over to the optical media.

This is also why many files you can download are provided a checksum to confirm post download that the checksum matches the original posters checksum, and once downloaded you can verify that a file has not been changed.

### Supporting Resources

- [What Is a Checksum (and Why Should You Care)?](https://www.howtogeek.com/363735/what-is-a-checksum-and-why-should-you-care/)
- [Conditions That Affect CDs and DVDs](https://www.clir.org/pubs/reports/pub121/sec5/)
- [Optical media preservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_media_preservation)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess I'll try adding checksums to my data and burn it along the data. And I also will take a look at adding parity like par2

Comment: @pauel Confirm the integrity of files by running checksums at the known-good source. Validate the checksums on newly written/copied media to ensure consistency with the original. Verify both initial and new checksum values post-copy. Save these checksums in the archive for ongoing validation. Ensuring the checksum values do not change will be checksum validation. Please ensure you validate these as that's the purpose, so just recording the checksum alone is not enough.